# AutoRedirect webpage from a javascript in a web server

Tags: javascript

I have a web server having around 20 web pages, now i want a javaScript, which can automatically redirect me from page 1 -> page 2 -> page 3 and so on, after certain intervals, what method should i use ? Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: Care to put some code into your question? Maybe show the navigation (which I'm assuming contains all pages to be navigated to) or give some detail on the names of your pages.

Comment: This sounds very much like a slide show of web pages, I would be tempted to adapt a existing javascript slide show (loads on the net) and make it display html instead of jpg, redirect after intervals is going to lead to issues with user intervention e.t.c, and i would guess issues with page load times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a javascript implementation. It uses onload to start after all assets and such have been loaded. It uses an array of the paths you want to navigate through and uses a `page_duration` variable to determine when to switch to the next page.

```
window.onload = function() {
    // array of all the paths to the pages you have
    var paths = ["page1.html", "page2.html", "page3.html"];

    // Amount of time to spend on each page (in ms)
    var page_duration = 10000;

    var path = window.location.pathname;
    // handles the case where the path ends in "/"
    if (path.length == path.lastIndexOf('/')+1) {
        path = path.substr(0,path.length-1);
    }
    var last_page = paths[paths.length-1];
    var curr_page = path.substr(path.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    var next_page = (curr_page == last_page) ? paths[0] : paths[paths.indexOf(curr_page)+1];

    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(curr_page, next_page);
    }, pageDuration);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<body>
        <h3><u>Navigate from one page to another using javascript without using Anchor tag.</u></h3>
        <br>
        <input type="button" value="go to next page" onclick="location.href='nextpage.htm' " ID="B1">
        <br>
        <div>
            <h5><u>View source code(below).</u></h5>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="go to next page" 
            onclick="location.href='nextpage.htm' " ID="B1">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

you can put your own method using this function and navigate to the target page every time or period you want 
mark as answered if it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it either by using HTML meta refresh http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh or by setting the window.location.href using JavaSript: http://programming.top54u.com/Samples/Javascript/Location-Object/Location-Href/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Add meta tag on each page like

```
// page 1 
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://urdomain.com/page2.htm">

// page 2
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://urdomain.com/page3.htm">

// page 3
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=http://urdomain.com/page4.htm">

.....
```

Number 2 in syntax is to refresh after 2 min.

JS approach:

1. Get the url, using document.location.href
2. Modify this url string to get next page
3. set `location.href = "new url"`
4. Add this script on all the pages

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically redirect after some interval, you want a combination of [`setTimeout()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Window.setTimeout) and [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location)

e.g.

```
function redirect() {
    window.location = "www.google.com";
}

setTimeout(redirect, 1000);
```